# How does CSS allocate space for columns in a grid where each column width is defined by a minmax() function with fixed values?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, minmax

I hope the question title makes sense. If not, here is a specific scenario:

Let's say we have an element like so:

```
main {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) minmax(250px, 255px) minmax(100px, 150px);
}
```

So this main element is a grid that has 500px of width to work with. How is the width of each individual column determined?

Is it a greedy approach where the first column takes 300px, the second takes up 200px and the last gets 0px?

But if we assign column widths based on the min values then the first would take up 200px, the second 250px, leaving 50px for the last column to take up.

I'm hoping to understand how space for each column is allocated in this particular scenario, so as to have a thorough understanding of CSS grid if I will end up using it going forward.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened when you tested this?

Comment: Upon inspecting the elements the column widths are
200px for the first
250px for the second
100px for the third

Which are all the min values. But these total to 550px, which is greater than the width of the grid container.

Comment: In any case though, I'm hoping to understand how things are *actually* calculated as opposed to make an observation that makes sense to me but turns out is actually incorrect.

Comment: _ *But these total to 550px, which is greater than the width of the grid container.*  you should give coherent values prior to start testing, you are starting with an incoherent setting and it goes wrong from the start. flex-grow and flex-shrink are not avalaible for grid if this was your question ;)

Comment: need a moment to cook an answer because the calculation is not trivial but interesting to understand

Comment: @TemaniAfif would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Not sure who is closing this question as opinion based or need more focus. The question is perfectly clear and requires some good understanding of the Spec to be answered. That's the type of the question we need here. If you don't understand it or cannot answer it, skip it and don't vote to close a perfect valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the trivial case where you have a width equal to `550px`. Each element will logically use its **minimum value** and since they cannot get smaller you will have the same configuration from `0px` to `550px` which will result in an overflow.

The other case is when you have a width equal to or bigger than `705px` where all your elements will use their **maximum value**.

Between `550px` and `705px`, the browser will try to divide the space equally while respecting the minmax boundaries. Each item has a **base size** (the minimum value) and a **growth limit** (the maximum value).

Let's take an example of `600px`. All the columns start at their base size:

```
200px | 250px | 100px
```

Then the browser will increase all the sizes at the same time and once a column reaches its **grow limit** we stop.

We will first reach the point

```
205px | 255px | 105px
```

And we stop for the second column because it reaches the maximum value but we continue for the other columns. Notice that we still have `35px` of free space and this space can be divided between the first and third column without reaching their max value to end with:

```
222.5px | 255px | 122.5px
```

```css
main {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) minmax(250px, 255px) minmax(100px, 150px);
  outline: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
}

main>* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Let's try with `650px`. We follow the same logic (I let you do it alone) and we end with:

```
247.5px | 255px | 147.5px
```

```css
main {
  width: 650px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) minmax(250px, 255px) minmax(100px, 150px);
  outline: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
}

main>* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Temani, thank you so much for taking the time to provide this answer. Makes a lot of sense. So just to make sure I have this right:

If the sum of the min values of the column widths is greater than the available width in the grid container, the column widths will take on the min value, and thus there will be overflow.

Comment: @journeywithjavascript yes, you cannot get smaller than the min value. You can manually adjust the width of the container from 0px to a big value and you will see how it behaves. All the values must remain between the min and max

Comment: And in the case where the sum of the min values of the column widths is less than the available width in the grid container, and the sum of the max values of the column widths is greater than the available width in the grid container, each column will start with their min value for their column width. They will each then be increased simultaneously until either the total available width in the grid container is reached, or the individual column width max value is reached. Does that sound right?

Comment: @journeywithjavascript yes